# I need to compare column structure of two tables in different databases but on the same instance in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to compare column structure of two tables in different databases but on the same instance in SQL Server 2016!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, can u please give us more information

Comment: I will be moving data from DB A to DB B they have same tables but before i move the data i have to confirm similarity of table structure

Answer (score 1):

Use [System Information Schema Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql). This should get you started:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to get information of column structure in a database and compare against another db

```
use DB
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is external software, but unless you have Visual Studio premium where the functionality is built in, you can use something like [Red Gate Schema Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index) as a trial version to compare and generate a script to synchronise your tables, stored procedures etc.